# How can I filter a permutation list depending of a pattern?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering, permutation

I've created a permutation list

```
Grid[Permutations[{a, e, q, r, t, u}], Frame -> All]
```

and only want to see rows where the 5th element is a "t". I tried to do use FilterRules, but I don't understand how to use them as shown below.

```
Grid[FilterRules[Permutations[{a, e, q, r, t, u}], Frame -> All], {, , , , t,}]
```

Could somebody please help me.

Comment: `Cases[Permutations[{a, e, q, r, t, u}], {Repeated[_, {4}], t, _}]`, which you can then wrap in `Grid` for presentation as well: `Grid[Cases[ ... ], Frame -> All]`.

Comment: `FilterRules` is for handling options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to MarcoB, there is the final code:

```
Grid[
  Cases[Permutations[{a, e, q, r, t, u}], {Repeated[_, {4}], t, _}], 
  Frame -> All]
```

Answer (score 6):

Just some other approaches:

```
perm = Permutations[{a, e, q, r, t, u}];
pm = Permutations[{a, e, q, r, u}];
```

The following:

```
pck = Pick[perm, #[[5]] & /@ perm, t];
sel = Select[perm, #[[5]] == t &];
con = #[[1 ;; 4]]~Join~{t}~Join~{#[[5]]} & /@ pm;
```

Comment: I'd do equivalently `con = Most@#~Join~{t, Last@#} & /@ pm`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP yes...thank you

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I did not interpret it as rude but as a useful comment. Comments and edits are part of the nice learning environment of the site. Sometimes I miss the obvious, am unusually ham-fisted, over complicate and sometimes I am just trying to be illustrative of the wonderful variety...so thank you not  sarcasm...if you want to edit feel free...just thought comment thread enough :)